# Using jquery-interdependencies-master, .include id for two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using jquery (jquery-interdependecies-master) to create a form.  I cannot figure out how to make an element hide and appear for two values.  One is easy, but if you try to tie it to two values, it will only show the last value listed in the rules.

Here's what I have:

```
     <style>

    #container {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #container > div {
        margin-bottom;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div>
            <label>Diet</label>
            <select id="diet">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="normal">Normal</option>
         <option value="gluten">Gulten Free</option>
         <option value="veggie">veggitarian</option>
    </select>
        </div>

        <div id="special-diet" style="margin-left">
            <label for="text">
                What kind of considerations
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="text" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>
                <span>Stay in hotel?</span>
                <input type="checkbox" id="accomodation">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div id="adults" style="margin-left">
            <label>Number of adults</label>
            <input type="number" />
        </div>

        <div id="children" style="margin-left">
            <label>Number of children (younger than 12-years-old)</label>
            <input type="number" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="deps.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Start creating a new ruleset
            var ruleset = $.deps.createRuleset();

            // Show diet text input option only when special diet option is selected
            var dietRule = ruleset.createRule("#diet", "==", "gluten");
            dietRule.include("#special-diet");
            var dietRule = ruleset.createRule("#diet", "==", "veggie");
            dietRule.include("#special-diet");
    //"veggie" rule displays "special-diet", but "gluten" will not

            // Make these fields visible when user checks hotel accomodation
            var hotelRule = ruleset.createRule("#accomodation", "==", true);
            hotelRule.include("#adults");
            hotelRule.include("#children");

            // Make the ruleset effective on the whole page
            ruleset.install();
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer:

```
var dietRule = ruleset.createRule("#diet", "!==", "normal");
         dietRule.include("#special-diet");
```

//the "!" is not equal

Comment: hi i am using jquery-interdependencies as well. But i am stuck with the following: i like to apply a ruleset to a multi select option menu. Like ` <select name="food" id="food" class="selectpicker" multiple>` and with the rulesets like `    var foodRuleMustard = ruleset.createRule("[name=food[]]", "==", "mustard");
                foodRuleMustard.include("#num_of_mustard");`